# Can't install VirtualBox Guest Additions in Kali Linux virtual machine under Debian (problems installing the kernel-headers)

Tags: kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I was trying to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions in a Kali Linux virtual machine by following the steps [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/286935).

I ran: `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade`, `sudo reboot` (until truly all packages were upgraded) `sudo apt-get install build-essential` `sudo apt-get install module-assistant`, `sudo m-a prepare`

But when I ran `sudo sh VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` I got:

> Installing additional modules ...
>   vboxadd.sh: Starting the VirtualBox Guest Additions.
>   Failed to set up service vboxadd, please check the log file

In the log file it says:

> vboxadd.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vboxadd-install.log to find out what went wrong.
>   vboxadd.sh: failed: modprove vboxgues failed.

Most likely this was due to not having the kernel headers installed.

Hence I ran `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname-r)` but then I get:

> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.9.0-kali3-amd64

`apt-cache search linux-headers` only shows:

> linux-headers-4.12.0-kali1-all - [...]
>   [...]

My question is: why am I having this problem and how can it be solved?
(Could it be a problem with my host system, is it maybe a problem of having executed something in a wrong order, should I maybe reinsert Guest Additions iso somehow?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple. It worked with `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-4.12.0-kali2-all`. Use `uname -r` to find out which package you need. Also note that you may need to change permissions of VBoxLinuxAdditions: `chmod 777 VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Comment: Glad to see you solved it. I have never had to change permissions to LinuxAdditions, for me `cp VBoxLinuxAdditions.run /tmp` then `/tmp$VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` just does it all the time.